# how to connect office365 api with .net

Tags: .net, office365

My requirement is i want to connect with Office API to show all events from my calender's and contacts to my application.

I followed same steps, whatever mentioned in below article, but not success.
https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet

Steps I have followed, 
1. I have created trial account on portal.office.com 
2. Registered my localhost apps to apps.dev.microsoft.com 
3. I have updated latest client_id and Client_Secret in my application.
4. Run MVC application, first time it ask to accept term and condition then after its showing below error.

**Sign In 

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. 

We received a bad request.**

I have spend couple of days but still its not working.
If anyone knows about it, please help me on this.

Comment: make sure you get latest updates for all your nuget packages in your project. Check the following on top of Client Id and Client Secret: Tenant Id and you have login capability when you registered your app in o365 AD.

Comment: Also, right click on your project - click on Add -> Connected Services and then make sure you are logged in to the right tenant with your Id and grant the right permissions, this will refresh your web.config. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: If Mostafa's suggestions don't help, it would be good to get a Fiddler trace of the repro (with SSL traffic decrypted) and look at the requests and responses to login.microsoftonline.com.

Comment: Its started to working now. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

have you entered your localhost-Address as redirect URL?
An there is also an Option to Register your App as Web oder Desktop App.
Did you choose the right one?

Regards,
Oliver